# PHP Error Retrieving Data From Remote Database (Not Populating Query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The following code takes data from a form to be retrieved from a remote database.

```
$find = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST['name']);

    echo ' '.$find;

$query_seek = mysqli_query($connect,  "SELECT * FROM test_2 WHERE NAME = '$find' ");

    if($query = $query_seek)
    {
        echo 'query successful';
    }
```

When I run it, the query does not seem to resolve or echo any data. Could it be as simple as using a get method versus post? I prefer to not have the query pass through the URL for security but if can't be helped so be it. I assume the syntax for the SQL to be correct as I ran it on the server side through PHPMyAdmin's SQL client. Anything glaringly incorrect?

This block comes after a check where the input is verified for length and no white space.

Comment: You're using an assignment in your conditional `if($query = $query_seek)` should use `==` instead. also, you're never doing anything with the result set, so why are you comparing a database object against (who knows what as we don't know what $query is)

Comment: GET vs. POST is no difference in case of security. you query the database, but you dont `mysqli_fetch_*` the result.

Comment: Good point. So could I in theory simply pass ($query_seek) to the if and if it evaluates true the inside block is executed?

Comment: oh and btw.. i would highly recomend prepared statements (and if you wanna make your live easier.. use PDO)